# Adding a newline to a file

Tags: ruby, file-io

How do you write a newline to a file in Ruby?

My code to write to the file is:

[Full code request]

```
print("Word:")                                  #Prompt for word to scrambe
word = gets.chomp                               #Inputs word
wordLength = word.length                        #Gets word length
randomAmount = wordLength * wordLength          #Finds out how many ways to randomize
amountDone = 0                                  #Loop variable for process of randomizing
while amountDone != randomAmount
puts "---------------------------\n"
x = word.chars.to_a.shuffle                 #Changes each character to an array and randomizez them
File.open("output.txt","a+") {|f| f.write(x)}
puts "#{amountDone}:\n #{x}"                
amountDone += 1
puts "---------------------------\n"
end
puts "Type any key to continue..."
endWord = gets.chomp                            #Close program prompt
```

-

```
File.open("output.txt","a+") {|f| f.write(x) }
```

But the problem is that that line ^ is in a loop. Meaning it's repeated over and over again quite a lot of times actually. So whenever you open the output file, the output is squashed together. So what the program I've wrote basically does is it scrambles words into as many ways as possible. So if my input was "Abcdefgh", then the output in the file is going to be displayed as one continuous line:

> bdfcegAhhbgfeAcdhcedbAgfdfcAhgebefcdbghAdAfhegbcAegdfhbcbchdgefAhAbedfcgdAfcbhgefhgdAbceefdhcgAbAefbhgcdfAcebdhgAebgchfddhcfAbegcAdfbhgecAgdfhebedAghbfcedbAchgfbhAcgfdeceghAbfddAbfehcgbAhefdgcecfghbdAAhcgdfbedchAgfbebfhAgecdedAhcbgfAfdceghbehdcAbfgcegdhbfAfdAbchgegAhbfecdgeAdhfcbcbdAehfgfhgbcAedchdgbefAfhecdAbgAbedgcfhehcgfbdAAhgcebfdbAcehgfddfchgebAhcAbegdffAbehgcdchdbgAfebeAhgdfcbegcdhfAfecbdhAgdbfehgAcdbcehgfAgdehfcbAbgedAcfhdgcAfehbdfhAgecbcAgdhebfghbAefcdgebhAfdcgecdbAfhgbcAhfedhAbfgdcebAedfhcgbdfchAge

So, what I want to do is I want to have some sort of separation between the output. So every time it's outputted there is either a new line, a space, a pipe, a slash, etc.

I've already tried

```
File.open("output.txt","a+") {|f| f.write(x)+" " }
```

and

```
File.open("output.txt","a+") {|f| f.write(x)," " }
```

and

```
File.open("output.txt","a+") {|f| f.write(x)" " }
```

but it doesn't work. So how might I be able to solve this?

Comment: In Ruby, people use `word_length`, not `wordLength`: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#naming

Comment: I've found the solution but I have to wait 6 hours to post it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I figured out this solution I actually laughed at how ridiculously simple it was.

All I really had to do was add the spacing separately along with the line. So for:

```
File.open("output.txt","a+") {|f| f.write(x) }
```

all that needed to be done was to add this line:

```
File.open("output.txt","a+") {|f| f.write(" ") }
```

so it would be:

```
File.open("output.txt","a+") {|f| f.write(x) }
File.open("output.txt","a+") {|f| f.write(x) }      #This is hilarious
```

So the solution was quite simple all along, although if there are more simple solutions(perhaps code on one line instead of 2).

I think @seph's answer actually worked though, but still in the same way where it wrote it letter by letter then a space. I think it would write each individually if you changed "puts" to "write".

```
File.open('testfile.txt', 'a+') do |f|
(1..3).each do |i|
f.puts("#{x} #{randomAmount}")
end
end

#change that to

File.open('output.txt', 'a+') do |f|
(randomAmount).each do |i|
f.write("#{amountDone}:\n#{x}")
end
end
```

and then I think it works. I don't know for certain since the time I tried this it actually worked or not because I had misplaced my output.txt file and so I assumed the empty one in my home directory had the output (which wasn't true) so I got the wrong idea.

But thanks to all who tried!

Answer (score 5):

```
File.open("output.txt","a+") { |f| f.puts(x) }
```

should do it

Edit:

You could append a newline to x like this:

```
x + "\n"
```

Edit 2:

You want open the file outside of the loop. Try this:

```
File.open('testfile.txt', 'a+') do |f|
  (1..3).each do |i|
    f.puts("test #{i}")
  end
end
```

It works on my machine(MBP). It puts 3 lines in the file:

```
test 1
test 2
test 3
```

Comment: Not exactly... It's just kind of different, but there's still no actual separation. I mean, there's new lines but it's new lines in between each letter.

Comment: @lakam99 you should probably post a little more code then, to show the context this is being used in.

Comment: @seph 
do i place it in the same line as the file.open? Because that doesn't work.

Comment: I understand how that should've worked with only that piece of code in the file, but I think you should try applying that with my code. Because I did, and I'm not sure if I did it wrong or something but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

On the simplest level you can simply add another `write` statement:

```
separator = '\n' # or space, tab, etc
...
File.open("output.txt","a+") {|f|
    f.write(x)
    f.write(separator)
}
```

Combining the two `write` calls should work as well:

```
separator = '\t'
...
File.open("output.txt","a+") {|f| f.puts(x + separator) }
```

Comment: actually this sort of is like my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the parenthesis around the " " as well as the x.

```
File.open("output.txt","a+") {|f| f.write(x)+" " }
```

should be changed to

```
File.open("output.txt","a+") {|f| f.write(x + " ") }
```

Comment: Tried 6 different ways:
File.open("output.txt","a+") {|f| f.write(x)(" ")}; File.open("output.txt","a+") {|f| f.write(x)+(" ")};
File.open("output.txt","a+") {|f| f.write(x),(" ")};
File.open("output.txt","a+") {|f| f.write(x+(" "))};
File.open("output.txt","a+") {|f| f.write(x,(" "))};
File.open("output.txt","a+") {|f| f.write(x(" "))};
Unfortunately none worked.

Comment: what Andrew meant was that you need to make it look like this: `File.open("output.txt","a+") { |f| f.write(x + " ") }`

Comment: Oh...Well I tried that now since it's cleared up (I think) but unfortunately it didn't work once again...