# How to append a new line write to a file with ruby?

Tags: ruby, file

My code is:

```
def write_to_file(line, my_file)
  File.open(my_file, 'a') do |file|
    p '-----loop number:' + line.id.to_s
    file.puts "#{line.id}"
  end
end
```

If I loop three times with this method, I can see:

```
-----loop number:1
-----loop number:2
-----loop number:3
```

But it can only write the last id into my_file. Even I tried:

```
file << "#{line.id}"
# or
file.write "#{line.id}\n"
```

The result was the same.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506856/adding-a-newline-to-a-file

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with the given code.

Comment: Could you show the content of your file after running the code and the content you were expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
def write_to_file(line, my_file)
  File.open(my_file, 'a') do |file|
     p '-----loop number:' + line.to_s
     file.puts "#{line}"
  end
end

[1,2,3,4].each do |line|
  write_to_file(line, my_file)
end
```

Comment: Apparently, the OP's `line` is an object with an `id` attribute. I don't think removing that detail solves the problem, does it?

Comment: No removing id its not solution i just write here an simple example which is append your result in your file so look in your loop method its like this or not